# How to make Lasagne layers nontrainable

Tags: python, lasagne

I want to use a pretrained neural network and just fine-tune it to my specific needs.  I wanted to use Python and the Lasagne framework for this.  On:

https://github.com/Lasagne/Recipes/blob/master/examples/ImageNet%20Pretrained%20Network%20%28VGG_S%29.ipynb

I found an example of how to use a pretrained network for specific images.  My problem is that I would like to use 
the network described in the link above as a starting point and add a final layer to it that makes it implement a TWO CLASS
classifier which is what I need.  I therefore wanted to keep all the layers in the network frozen and allow training ONLY in my last added layer.

Apparently there is a way to indicate that layers should be "nontrainable" in lasagne, but I have found no expemples of how to do this on the web.

Any thoughts on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Set those layers that you want to frozen with lr to be 0 and only set those layer you want to fine tune lr nonzero. There is not a online example yet. But you should check this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lasagne-users/2z-6RrgiHkE

Answer (score 0):

Remove `trainable` tag from all parameters of the layers that you want to keep frozen:

```py
def freeze_layer(layer):
    for param in layer.params.values():
         param.remove('trainable')
```

To freeze all your network up to a certain layer you can simply iterate over its lower layers:

```py
from lasagne.layers import get_all_layers

def freeze_net(net):
    layers = get_all_layers(net)
    for l in layers:
        freeze_layer(l)
```

Code untested. See [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lasagne-users/D2mVVMNdaBs) for more info.